# SQL Server 2008 XML replace element values with text from other element values

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008

With the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[GDB_ITEMS](
    [ObjectID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Type] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](226) NULL,
    [PhysicalName] [nvarchar](226) NULL,
    [Path] [nvarchar](512) NULL,
    [Url] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Properties] [int] NULL,
    [Defaults] [varbinary](max) NULL,
    [DatasetSubtype1] [int] NULL,
    [DatasetSubtype2] [int] NULL,
    [DatasetInfo1] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [DatasetInfo2] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [Definition] [xml] NULL,
    [Documentation] [xml] NULL,
    [ItemInfo] [xml] NULL,
    [Shape] [geometry] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [R2_pk] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ObjectID] ASC
)
```

The xml column `documentation` contains this element group 1:

```
<spdom>
  <bounding>
    <westbc>-84.007769</westbc>
    <eastbc>-83.037582</eastbc>
    <northbc>35.790660</northbc>
    <southbc>35.418718</southbc>
  </bounding>
</spdom>
```

and this element group 2:

```
<GeoBndBox esriExtentType="search">
  <westBL Sync="TRUE">-84.024010</westBL>
  <eastBL Sync="TRUE">-82.992641</eastBL>
  <northBL Sync="TRUE">35.845552</northBL>
  <southBL Sync="TRUE">35.417139</southBL>
  <exTypeCode Sync="TRUE">1</exTypeCode>
</GeoBndBox>
```

What I'd like to do, programmatically, is replace the values in group1 with the values in group 2. E.g, `westbc` and `westBL` are the same definition, so I'd like to replace -84.007769 with -84.024010. Attempting to do this on several thousand records in gdb_items, each with different text values in that element group. Thanks!

Comment: (I'm assuming that `documents` should be `Documentation`)  What do you mean by "element group"?  Do you mean that `Documentation` contains a larger XML document, and `spdom` and `GeoBndBox` are two elements in that document?

Comment: yes, that was a typo. Spdom and Geobndbox are just two elements in the xml document which is stored in the [documentation] column. There are serveral hundred elements in this document, which is FGDC Metadata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [replace value of (XML DML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190675.aspx).

The syntax used to replace the value of `westbc` with `10` looks like this.

```
update GDB_ITEMS
set Documentation.modify(
  'replace value of (//spdom/bounding/westbc/text())[1] with "10"')
```

And to get hold of the value you need you would use something like this:

```
select Documentation.value('(//GeoBndBox/westBL)[1]', 'varchar(20)')
from GDB_ITEMS
```

Putting those two together in one update statement.

```
update T
set Documentation.modify(
  'replace value of (//spdom/bounding/westbc/text())[1] 
   with sql:column("S.Value")')
from GDB_ITEMS as T
  cross apply (select T.Documentation.value('(//GeoBndBox/westBL)[1]', 
                                            'varchar(20)')) as S(Value)
```

It is not possible to replace the value in more than one node at a time so you have to repeat this for every node. You can do it quite nicely in a loop using a map table that has the source node name and the target node name.

```
declare @Map table
(
  ID int identity primary key,
  TargetNode varchar(7),  
  SourceNode varchar(7)
)

insert into @Map values
('westbc',  'westBL'),
('eastbc',  'eastBL'),
('northbc', 'northBL'),
('southbc', 'southBL')

declare @ID int = 1

while @ID <= 4
begin
  update T 
  set Documentation.modify('replace value of 
                              (//spdom/bounding/*[local-name(.)=sql:column("M.TargetNode")]/text())[1] 
                            with sql:column("S.Value")')
  from GDB_ITEMS as T
    cross apply (select TargetNode, SourceNode from @Map where ID = @ID) as M
    cross apply (select Documentation.value('(//GeoBndBox/*[local-name(.)=sql:column("M.SourceNode")])[1]', 'varchar(20)')) as S(Value)
  
  set @ID += 1
end
```

Try here: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/59329/new

Comment: as usual, your code logic is impeccable. I'm running into a block with the '<GeoBndBox esriExtentType="search">' element. When using your text, 'GeoBndBox', I get 'Mutator 'modify()' on 'Documentation' cannot be called on a null value.'. When I use 'GeoBndBox esriExtentType="search"' it returns 'Incorrect syntax near '='.'

Comment: @tpcolson The `mutator` error is because your column is null. Try to add a where clause `where Documentation is not null`.

Comment: Can you please help with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32974700/why-do-i-receive-a-mutator-error-when-modifying-an-xml-value-in-sql